# Using Linkedin API with google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

aloha all,

Im create a integration with linkedin and google apps script, for post in company page.

All is good, in terms of oauth2, i have the tokens, but the problem is the body request, look:

```
var payload = {"visibility": {"code": "anyone"},"comment": "Testing a full company share!","content": {"submitted-­url": "https://www.google.com","title": "Test Share with Content","description": "content description","submitted‐image-­url": "https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg"}};
var headers = {Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Service.getAccessToken()};
var options = {method:'post',headers:headers,payload:payload,muteHttpExceptions:true};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/2414183/shares?format=json", options);
```

THE REQUES IS GOOD, BECAUSE I USE APIGEE FOR TEST MY JSON REQUEST. THIS IS THE RESPONSE OF THE SERVER:

```
[16-12-12 22:38:13:411 EST] {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Couldn't parse share document: error: Unexpected element: CDATA",
  "requestId": "XNZ80U0LCX",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1481600293335
}
```

IN SEVERAL FORUMS SAY THAT THE HEARDER I SHOUD PUT:

'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-li-format': 'json'

BUT WHEN PUT THIS CODE ON HEADER THE ERROR OF SERVER IS:

```
[16-12-12 22:40:00:344 EST] {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Couldn't parse Json body: Unexpected character ('v' (code 118)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@c3576e8; line: 1, column: 2]",
  "requestId": "YQFPJKZTMC",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1481600400231
}
```

THANKS ALL﻿

Answer (score 2):

For payload you need to provide valid JSON e.g.:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(object):
```

Not:

```
var payload = object;
```

I'd also add the content type to the headers, setting it to `application/json`:

```
var options = {
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.example.com', options);
```

Answer (score 2):

One change... Per the Linkedin developer docs:

> If you opt to provide a JSON-formatted body, make sure your HTTP request includes the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
x-li-format: json
```

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin